# Typescript: Return data not assignable to conditional type

Tags: typescript

In the code example below I'm getting the following errors in `getThingData`. As best as I can tell, the type is correct and calling it from elsewhere returns the expected result (and Typescript know which type would be returned).

1. `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ThingData<T>'. ts(2322)`
2. `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ThingData<T>'. ts(2322)`

Does anyone know how to get rid of the error?

```js
type Thing1 = { name: string };
type Thing2 = { notName: boolean };

function getThing1Data(thing: Thing1) {
    return thing.name;
}

function getThing2Data(thing: Thing2) {
    return thing.notName;
}

function isThing2(thing: any): thing is Thing2 {
    return !!thing.notName;
}

type ThingData<T extends Thing1 | Thing2> = T extends Thing1
    ? ReturnType<typeof getThing1Data>
    : ReturnType<typeof getThing2Data>;

function getThingData<T extends Thing1 | Thing2>(
    thing: T
): ThingData<T> {
    if (isThing2(thing)) return getThing2Data(thing);

    return getThing1Data(thing);
}

const thing1 = { name: 'bob' };
const thing2 = { notName: true };

console.log(getThingData(thing1));
console.log(getThingData(thing2));
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAFQBYEsB2BzAjHAvHAbzjQEMBbGALjgGcwAndDOAXwG5RJZFVMAmPIWIB7MADlyVWgyasOIUADMArmgDGYFMLRwMMMMiZYAIiTAkAFGF4ZqhzFgCUhUHDdx6+5fR3WmAOlIKeRZQJVUNLR09Axs+U3MrGzs45wJXd08wb18bQNEJYNBQhRAVdU1tOBQaeww+JKZqEjQIR2o-TGqaHiYBdJB3Dy8fOABCMc6MfPFJELDwaHg6hJIAHgQ4GAAPMBg0ABMeupwAH17+AD5BTZ29w+ObLAy3AH44ACURtAQlta4YMJFLp9CdVpcXnBqF9sj5frB-ksgSDYn1wfJwhUoiiVmZ1rddvsjhdsHBznU+JcLJCpnZQO0SasNtcBkMUMCLDUKY1MI5nFkcji4qseRhHBjBplvkKjCKpuLigs1No6HApjh8EQglIAOQAI2Eep1clAyrQqqmAk1IlmFGoOoOMEU6BQewANhAbXADUaTaUzTRhG6YP43cIMBYYrjEuq+fIA0GQ2GI1GbHLUuKgA)

Comment: I would just coerce the type of the return value (tack `as ThingData<T>` after each of the `return getThingNData(thing)` calls).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Coercing the result works but it doesn't seem like it should be necessary

Comment: This is [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912); conditional types depending on unspecified generic type parameters are essentially opaque to the compiler.  It can't use control flow like the result of `isThing2(thing)` to narrow the type parameter `T`; it only narrows the type of `thing`.  For now a type assertion is the best you can do unless you want to use the `conditionalProducingIf` workaround from the GitHub issue.  Let me know if you want to see an answer with this info in more detail.

Comment: @jcalz That's my issue exactly. Thanks for the github issue link. I wish I could mark a comment as the answer.

Comment: There are actually two things going on here, and depending which one is your primary issue the answer could be different.  Would you mind if we changed `Thing2` to be `type Thing2 = { notName: number };` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0obRN) so that `ThingData<T>` looks like `T extends Thing1 ? string : number`?  Or does your question specifically have to do with both sides of the conditional type being identical like `T extends Thing1 ? string : string`?

Answer (score 0):

Both `getThing1Data` and `getThing2Data` return type is `string`. Return type of `getThingData` is explicitly `ThingData<T>`. Hence the error.

If you remove `: ThingData<T>` from `getThingData` signature, everything will work, as TS will implicitly deuce that return type should be `string`.

Comment: This is a contrived example (with the goal of being as simple as possible to see the issue). It may have been oversimplified for this case. The real code returns different objects and I need the compiler to know which is being returned.

Comment: I edited the example to be a little more useful

Comment: @Dianoga ok, what are different objects/type? What do you mean by ThinkData<T>. Do they have any common interface? If order for this to work both methods should return something that compiler will perceive a one.

Comment: @jcalz commented on the question with a github issue that exactly covers my issue